# running tests on github actions with FastAPI fails due to it trying to connect to hosted DB first

Tags: postgresql, continuous-integration, pytest, github-actions, fastapi

I'm trying to set up a CI pipeline using github actions but its failing. The reason that I think its failing is because FastAPI tries to first establish a connection with the production DB and then it runs the db override. Another theory is that the container could be "sandboxed" and this prevents connections to the production db.

Heres my workflow code:

```
name: Python application

on:
  push:
    branches: [ main ]
  pull_request:
    branches: [ main ]

jobs:
  build:

    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    # Service containers to run with `container-job`
    services:
      # Label used to access the service container
      postgres:
        # Docker Hub image
        image: postgres
        # Provide the password for postgres
        env:
          POSTGRES_USER: test
          POSTGRES_DB: test
          POSTGRES_PASSWORD: testing
        ports:
          - 5432:5432
        # Set health checks to wait until postgres has started
        options: >-
          --health-cmd pg_isready
          --health-interval 10s
          --health-timeout 5s
          --health-retries 5
    steps:
    - uses: actions/checkout@v2
    - name: Set up Python 3.9
      uses: actions/setup-python@v2
      with:
        python-version: 3.9
    - name: Install dependencies
      run: |
        cd backend
        python -m pip install --upgrade pip
        pip install flake8 pytest
        if [ -f requirements.txt ]; then pip install -r requirements.txt; fi
    - name: Lint with flake8
      run: |
        # stop the build if there are Python syntax errors or undefined names
        flake8 . --count --select=E9,F63,F7,F82 --show-source --statistics
        # exit-zero treats all errors as warnings. The GitHub editor is 127 chars wide
        flake8 . --count --exit-zero --max-complexity=10 --max-line-length=127 --statistics
    - name: Test with pytest
      env:
        NAME: ${{ secrets.NAME }}
        USERNAME: ${{ secrets.USERNAME }}
        PASSWORD: ${{ secrets.PASSWORD }}
        PORT: ${{ secrets.PORT }}
        URL: ${{ secrets.URL }}
      run: |
        cd backend
        python -m pytest tests/
```

And here is the code to setup the testing enviorment in FastAPI:

```
from fastapi.testclient import TestClient
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
from sqlalchemy.orm import sessionmaker
from database import Base, get_db
from main import app 
import json

SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://test:testing@localhost:5432/test'

engine = create_engine(
    SQLALCHEMY_DATABASE_URL, connect_args={}
)

TestingSessionLocal = sessionmaker(autocommit=False, autoflush=False, bind=engine)

Base.metadata.drop_all(bind=engine)
Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)

def override_get_db():
    try:
        db = TestingSessionLocal()
        yield db
    finally:
        db.close()

app.dependency_overrides[get_db] = override_get_db

client = TestClient(app)
```

This is the error:

```
E   sqlalchemy.exc.OperationalError: (psycopg2.OperationalError) could not connect to server: No such file or directory
E       Is the server running locally and accepting
E       connections on Unix domain socket "/var/run/postgresql/.s.PGSQL.5432"?
```

From the errors stacktrace i can see that the error starts with this line in my code, witch is part of the code that connects with the production db. This is located in main.py

```
models.Base.metadata.create_all(bind=engine)
```

Running the server works fine and running the tests locally also work fine, the problem only occurs when running the tests via github actions. Shouldn't FastAPI run the overrides first?

Comment: I think firstly the database needs to be created in that environment.